# How to insert Horizontal bar in NSCollectionView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

How to insert  Horizontal bar in NScollectionview like as below[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see [UICollectoinView horizontal scroll with inter item spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651464/uicollectoinview-horizontal-scroll-with-inter-item-spacing/14960243#14960243).
According to **Alexander** there are two ways :

**1.** `UICollectionViewController` size

**2.** `SectionEdgeInset`

Check the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14960243/1603072) given by Alexander.

There is a series of two Tutorials by **Ray Wenderlich**. You can also take a look at it :

**1.** [Part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)

**2.** [Part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)

GoodLuck.

Comment: i need in NSCollectionview not UICollectionView. question is not about  interview spacing and rayWanderlich tutorials are based on table view. UITableview is always embeded with a header and footer.