# UICollectionView Paging Offsets and Spacing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm stumped.  I've got this collection view showing the edges of cells as a hint for what's available with a swipe, but only the first and last cells appear properly.  Everything in between isn't lining up properly.  What am I missing?

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(280, 400);
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20);
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10;
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0;

self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.collectionView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

[image]

Comment: I also tried to do this and ultimately failed, the problem is a 'page' is considered to be the full 320px but you want it to actually scroll with width of itemSize :p  At the time I figured it'd involve subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` but abandoned the plan, looks like that may be the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13228600/155513

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue.  The problem, as I understand it, is that paging distance with `UIScrollView` is determined by the width of the scroll view.  `UICollectionView` is a `UIScrollView`.

I've found solutions to accomplish this peeking feature with a `UIScrollView` by making the `UIScrollView` narrower than your screen, turning on `pagingEnabled`, and turning off `clipsToBounds`.  To capture gestures from the edges of the screen, you can then embed the `UIScrollView` into a full-screen-width `UIView` that captures and passes gestures to the `UIScrollView`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31301232/3352624).

Since UICollectionView is a UIScrollView, I attempted the same approach with the `UICollectionView`.  Unfortunately with `UICollectionView` the adjacent cells only appear when they start to enter the `UICollectionView` (which was narrower than the screen in my case).  Yes, even with `clipsToBounds` off.   It just doesn't bother rendering any part of the cell until at least some part of the cell is visible within the `UICollectionView`.

So I've made my `UICollectionView` full-screen-width.  I'm now on a hunt to find a good way to customize the paging.

If that doesn't turn up with a slick solution, I will probably drop back to replacing the `UICollectionView` with a `UIScrollView` and layout my "cells" side-by-side by hand.

I'm also a bit concerned that we might run into problems with `UICollectionView` in this scenario since we don't have full control over the cell spacing. Notice you can only set the minimum and not a precise value.