# UICollectionView How to implement horizontal align scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, smooth-scrolling

I have a `UICollection` which is implemented and works, however I cannot achieve the scrolling I want.

Here is a picture of my `UICollectionView`, I have resized the grey cell to `250` by `250`.

[image]

My issue is, when I start scrolling, this is what happens.

My cell first starts off on the far left, but notice what happens if I start to scroll horizontally.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the seam between the cells moves over to the left the more I scroll through the cells. This is not what I want.

What I want to achieve is: the cell is aligned to the center, and when you scroll, instead of the center of the cells moving to the left more and more, I want the cell to stay in the middle. Much like a `PageViewController` does except I want it to be `UICollectionViewCells`.

I have tried adding in the following code for example:

```
    - (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    float pageWidth = 210;

    float currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    float targetOffset = targetContentOffset->x;
    float newTargetOffset = 0;

    if (targetOffset > currentOffset)
        newTargetOffset = ceilf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth;
    else
        newTargetOffset = floorf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth;

    if (newTargetOffset < 0)
        newTargetOffset = 0;
    else if (newTargetOffset > scrollView.contentSize.width)
            newTargetOffset = scrollView.contentSize.width;

        targetContentOffset->x = currentOffset;
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newTargetOffset, 0) animated:YES];
    }
```

Which achieves the even scrolling, however I want to have `paging` enabled aswell as `bounce`.

[image]

Because if I enable `paging` and `bounce`, the scrolling is very smooth and elegant, however If I use the code up above the scrolling is very rugged and mechanical.

So How can I achieve even scrolling that is smooth like apples default scrolling, with my `UICollectionViewCell` being centred in the middle?

If I didn't explain the problem well enough, this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228600/uicollectionview-align-logic-missing-in-horizontal-paging-scrollview) explains my problem except I am using one cell instead of three, and I want the scrolling to be smooth and bounce etc.

Comment: Have you tried your code with paging disabled?

Comment: Yes, it is still very mechanical and rugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work (disable paging):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
  if (!decelerate) {
    // do your calculations
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newTargetOffset, 0) animated:YES];
  }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  // do your calculations
  [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newTargetOffset, 0) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi almas what calculations do I do? Could you give me an example please?

Comment: just copy-paste your code that calculates 'newTargetOffset'

Comment: its not perfect but its pretty close, it will do for now.