# How to center align items in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView showing a number of images with horizontal scroll and paging enabled. The first and the last pages are showing perfectly but rest of the pages are not showing properly, they are showing parts of images from the adjacent page due to which they are not aligned properly (screenshots attached). How do I make all pages look same i.e. the images properly center aligned so that adjacent pages don't peek.

[image]
[image]

Notice the image peeking in Page 2 from the left side due to which the actual image on is getting clipped from the left. How can I fix this so that all pages look like page 1.

Comment: Try enabling paging in collectionview

Comment: I have already mentioned that paging is enabled.

Comment: As I can see there are only 3 cells which can fit in a row on screen, however even on the first screenshot last image is a little bit cropped. Is not it?

Comment: If you want to make paging, you should make sure that each your page is equal width. If you have collection view with width = 500 and you want to have 5 pages, you should have content size width equal to 2500, otherwise it will look weird and sometimes may crop pages.

Comment: It is not perfectly alright on your screenshot. I have checked in photoshop. Check it there: http://prntscr.com/8cemc4. You can see 10 pixels transparent on the right. That's how it should be. It means that your image is cropped.

Comment: I found a similar question which I hope is dealing with the same problem: [UICollectionView align logic missing in horizontal paging scrollview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228600/uicollectionview-align-logic-missing-in-horizontal-paging-scrollview) but the solutions are in Objective-C. If anyone could provide the code in swift.

Comment: Check my new answer. Added swift solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you have replied in the comment, answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228600/uicollectionview-align-logic-missing-in-horizontal-paging-scrollview). Here is the Swift solution you have asked for.

**Swift 1.2**

```
override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
    // Only support single section for now.
    // Only support Horizontal scroll
    let count = collectionView!.dataSource!.collectionView(collectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection: 0)

    let canvasSize = collectionView!.frame.size
    var contentSize = canvasSize

    if (scrollDirection == .Horizontal) {
        let rowCount = (canvasSize.height - itemSize.height) / (itemSize.height + minimumInteritemSpacing) + 1
        let columnCount = (canvasSize.width - itemSize.width) / (itemSize.width + minimumLineSpacing) + 1;
        let page = ceil(CGFloat(count) / (CGFloat)(rowCount * columnCount));
        contentSize.width = page * canvasSize.width;
    }

    return contentSize;
}

func frameForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGRect {
    let canvasSize = collectionView!.frame.size

    let rowCount = (canvasSize.height - itemSize.height) / (itemSize.height + minimumInteritemSpacing) + 1
    let columnCount = (canvasSize.width - itemSize.width) / (itemSize.width + minimumLineSpacing) + 1

    let pageMarginX = (canvasSize.width - columnCount * itemSize.width - (columnCount > 1 ? (columnCount - 1) * minimumLineSpacing : 0)) / 2.0
    let pageMarginY = (canvasSize.height - rowCount * itemSize.height - (rowCount > 1 ? (rowCount - 1) * minimumInteritemSpacing : 0)) / 2.0

    let page = CGFloat(indexPath.row) / (rowCount * columnCount)
    let remainder = CGFloat(indexPath.row) - page * (rowCount * columnCount)
    let row = remainder / columnCount
    let column = remainder - row * columnCount

    var cellFrame = CGRect.zeroRect
    cellFrame.origin.x = pageMarginX + column * (itemSize.width + minimumLineSpacing);
    cellFrame.origin.y = pageMarginY + row * (itemSize.height + minimumInteritemSpacing);
    cellFrame.size.width = itemSize.width;
    cellFrame.size.height = itemSize.height;

    if (scrollDirection == .Horizontal) {
        cellFrame.origin.x += page * canvasSize.width;
    }

    return cellFrame;
}

override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {
    var attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    attributes.frame = frameForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    return attributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let superAttrs = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    if let originAttrs = superAttrs as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] {
        var attrs = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for (index, var attr) in enumerate(originAttrs) {
            let indexPath = attr.indexPath
            let itemFrame = frameForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(itemFrame, rect) {
                attr = layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                attrs.append(attr)
            }
        }

        return attrs
    }

    return superAttrs;
}
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
    // Only support single section for now.
    // Only support Horizontal scroll
    let count = collectionView!.dataSource!.collectionView(collectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection: 0)

    let canvasSize = collectionView!.frame.size
    var contentSize = canvasSize

    if (scrollDirection == .Horizontal) {
        let rowCount = (canvasSize.height - itemSize.height) / (itemSize.height + minimumInteritemSpacing) + 1
        let columnCount = (canvasSize.width - itemSize.width) / (itemSize.width + minimumLineSpacing) + 1;
        let page = ceil(CGFloat(count) / (CGFloat)(rowCount * columnCount));
        contentSize.width = page * canvasSize.width;
    }

    return contentSize;
}

func frameForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGRect {
    let canvasSize = collectionView!.frame.size

    let rowCount = (canvasSize.height - itemSize.height) / (itemSize.height + minimumInteritemSpacing) + 1
    let columnCount = (canvasSize.width - itemSize.width) / (itemSize.width + minimumLineSpacing) + 1

    let pageMarginX = (canvasSize.width - columnCount * itemSize.width - (columnCount > 1 ? (columnCount - 1) * minimumLineSpacing : 0)) / 2.0
    let pageMarginY = (canvasSize.height - rowCount * itemSize.height - (rowCount > 1 ? (rowCount - 1) * minimumInteritemSpacing : 0)) / 2.0

    let page = CGFloat(indexPath.row) / (rowCount * columnCount)
    let remainder = CGFloat(indexPath.row) - page * (rowCount * columnCount)
    let row = remainder / columnCount
    let column = remainder - row * columnCount

    var cellFrame = CGRect.zeroRect
    cellFrame.origin.x = pageMarginX + column * (itemSize.width + minimumLineSpacing);
    cellFrame.origin.y = pageMarginY + row * (itemSize.height + minimumInteritemSpacing);
    cellFrame.size.width = itemSize.width;
    cellFrame.size.height = itemSize.height;

    if (scrollDirection == .Horizontal) {
        cellFrame.origin.x += page * canvasSize.width;
    }

    return cellFrame;
}

override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    attributes!.frame = frameForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    return attributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let superAttrs = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    if let originAttrs = superAttrs as [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]! {
        var attrs = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for (_, var attr) in originAttrs.enumerate() {
            let indexPath = attr.indexPath
            let itemFrame = frameForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(itemFrame, rect) {
                attr = layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
                attrs.append(attr)
            }
        }

        return attrs
    }

    return superAttrs;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Swift 1.2 or Swift 2.0? It has difference.

Comment: I found a solution in swift which is working: [Horizontal paging view custom layout](http://pastebin.com/Rc9YRxWV), can you please guide how to add a spacing between cells, because all that is missing is the cell spacing. The cells are sticking to one another without any space.

Comment: Collection view flow layout has _var_ called **minimumInteritemSpacing**. It defines the minimum spacing to use between items in the same row.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added Swift 2.0 solution.

Comment: Could you please tell where do I specify the **minimumInteritemSpacing**. I am learning Swift and am not much familiar with collectionview

Comment: Are you going to use subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout? If yes, then in *init* method you can say `minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0`.

Comment: If you are just started learning collection view with swift, then [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1) will be useful.

Comment: Please refer to my code [Horizontal paging view custom layout](http://pastebin.com/Rc9YRxWV). I added an init along with init(coder: ). Causes error.

Comment: *UICollectionViewLayout* does not have *minimumInteritemSpacing*, you should calculate it manually.

Comment: In you func *calculateCellFrameHorizontalPosition* you should add calculation for spacing.